# (mobile web development) how to make a circle with "border-radius:50%" when its width is percent 80%

Tags: html, css

I used to make a circle with "width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:50%" in PC;
But there is something wrong when I do the same thing in mobile, because the width in PC is "px", the width in mobile is "percent", so I can't ensure the width and the mobile in mobile is same;

```css
div{border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:50%;width:80%;height:???}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: will you sahre some code because no one can solve your problem until you show them what actually the problem is.

Comment: use em and media queries and you will be able to 50% for every screen size

Comment: @DhavalChheda after using em, the height and the width still can't same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding-top with the same value as your width.

```
div {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  padding-top: 80%; /* value same as width */
}
```

Comment: But I want to know why the padding-top is related the width? I considered only padding-left is related the width;

Comment: I think you got confused here. Yes, padding-left is related to width, and padding-top is related to height. And since you cannot hard-coded the height, so we need to use padding-top. Both must be equal to form a circle. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

- `border-radius: 50%` on a **square** (height = width) will always be
  a **circle**.
- And use **dynamic measurements** (%,rem,em,
  vh,vw). 
  I recommend both width and height with **vh** or width an height **vw**. 
  e.g.: `width: 50vw; height: 50vw;` *(if size larger than 50, may overflow)*
  Other dynamic measurements deform instead of overflowing. 
  you can test them here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkbfo832/1/

Comment: width: 80vw. and height: 80vw // 80vw = 80% of viewport's width. 
if you use both vw and vh. it'll be a rectangle with same aspect ratio as the screen. So by using either width and height as vw or width and height as vh, you'll have a square! Note: 80vh wouldn't fit the screen on a mobile. and 80vw might not fit the screen on a desktop. I'll send you a fiddle

Comment: yep, just tested the other dynamic measurements. All the others deform. Stick to either vw on both, or vh on both. Don't use a size too big or it'll overflow (try 50vw or less). https://jsfiddle.net/gkbfo832/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your `div` is a child element of a parent element whose height and width are  known, then you can use `%` as a means of relative size. For example, I explicitly set the `body` dimensions, and can make the `div` a percentage width/height of the `body`.

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The width of parent is same to the browser, but the height is unknown;